# ¿Cómo realizar varios pickerview en swift?

Tags: swift

pues yo tengo este código que me permite realizar un pickerview de un textflied, basicamente una lista desplegable. Pero necesito replicarlo 4 veces más en la misma pantalla y me da problemas si por ejemplo copio el contenido de las funciones con las otras variables o uso if's para cada una, ya que por ejemplo solo me salen las opciones de una y cuando elijo se rellenan todas. Entonces no sé muy bien cómo realizarlo para que en cada uno salga el pickerview pertinente.

```
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtfieldTAM: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldMASA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldCHEESE: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldING1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldING2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldING3: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var TotalBillLable: UILabel!
    
    let tamanio = ["Pequeña", "Mediana", "Grande"]
    let masa = ["Fina", "Gruesa", "Bordes rellenos"]
    let queso = ["Parmesano", "Chedar", "Mozarela"]
    let ing1 = ["Ninguno","Más queso", "Pollo", "Huevo"]
    let ing2 = ["Ninguno","Más queso", "Pollo", "Huevo"]
    let ing3 = ["Ninguno","Más queso", "Pollo", "Huevo"]
    
    var pickerview = UIPickerView()
    
    //SEPARACIÓN
    
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    var shoppingCart: CarritoViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerview.delegate = self
        pickerview.dataSource = self
        
        txtfieldTAM.inputView = pickerview
        txtfieldTAM.textAlignment = .center       
        
    }

}

extension CarritoFinalViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return tamanio.count
        
      
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return tamanio[row]
        
       
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        txtfieldTAM.text = tamanio[row]
        txtfieldTAM.resignFirstResponder()
        
       
      
    }
   
}
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea me salva la vida, gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcionalidad del `pickerView` para el resto de `textFields` es el mismo, lo que te falta es verificar que caja de texto hiciste tap y recargar los datos. Estas son sugerencias de cambios en tu código:

1. Agregar una variable en donde se van a almacenar los datos de cada array:

   ```
   var data: [String] = []
   ```
2. Los valores de ese array van a servir para llenar el `pickerView`:

   ```
   func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
       return 1
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
       return data.count
   }

   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
       return data[row]
   }
   ```
3. Agregamos el delegado del `textField`:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
   ```
4. Comprobamos en cuál `textField` se hizo tap, en la variable **data** almacenamos los valores y recargamos el `pickerView`:

   ```
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       if textField == self.textFieldOne {
          self.data = self.tamanio
       }
       if textField == self.textFieldTwo {
          self.data = self.masa
       }
       pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
   }
   ```
5. Mostramos el valor seleccionado del `pickerView` en el `textField` de acuerdo al que se hizo tap:

   ```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       if textFieldOne.isFirstResponder {
           textFieldOne.text = data[row]
           textFieldOne.resignFirstResponder()
       }
       if textFieldTwo.isFirstResponder {
           textFieldTwo.text = data[row]
           textFieldTwo.resignFirstResponder()
       }
   }
   ```
6. Asignamos los delegados y el `pickerView` a los `textField`:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       pickerview.delegate = self
       pickerview.dataSource = self

       textFieldOne.delegate = self
       textFieldTwo.delegate = self

       textFieldOne.inputView = pickerview
       textFieldOne.textAlignment = .center
       textFieldTwo.inputView = pickerview
       textFieldTwo.textAlignment = .center
   }
   ```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!